# Can I get element name by id in php?

Tags: php, html

Can I get element name by id in php?
for example I have

```
<td id="dist_td'.$i.'"><input type="hidden" name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="dist_'.$i.'" value="-" ></td>
```

I want with id get name or value(I know that I can do it in js, but I need to send name or value to Database)